# JavaFX Tableview does not bind with controller class (JDK 8)

Tags: java, java-8, javafx-8, fxml

I have updated my javaFX application from java 1.7 to java 1.8 . Now it seems that FXML TableView component does not bind with Java controller class reference. I have posted this question on [OTN community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3543548) too.Thanks.

FXML file:

```
<TableView fx:id="dvTypeTbl" layoutX="49.0" layoutY="145.0" prefHeight="388.0" prefWidth="800.0">

          <columns>

            <TableColumn maxWidth="5000.0" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="420.0" text="%device.type.main.view.table.column.name">

              <cellFactory>

                <com.stee.rcm.gui.fxml.FormattedTableCellFactory alignment="LEFT" />

              </cellFactory>

              <cellValueFactory>

                <PropertyValueFactory property="dtName" />

              </cellValueFactory>

            </TableColumn>          

          </columns>

</TableView>
```

**Java controller class:**

```
public class DeviceTypeMainController implements Initializable {

  @FXML private static TableView<DeviceTypeTable> dvTypeTbl;

  @Override

  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 

    // With this reference now it will get null pointer
    ObservableList<DeviceTypeTable> dtList = dvTypeTbl.getItems();

  }
}
```

Comment: Answered on OTN: don't make the injected field static.

Comment: @James_D Thanks for the feed back. But I have to make that so.. because it was refer with some static method

Comment: Make that method an instance method. You never need "global" data in a controller.